# ROS2: Preferred method of making worker threads

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, what is a preferred method of making worker threads in ROS2? If I would want real-time, should I use independently made rea- time threads, or is there an API for that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308230/ros2:-preferred-method-of-making-worker-threads/) by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2018-11-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no API for creating threads in ROS 2. The Executor class calls callbacks (if that's what you mean), and if you want a different threading model from `SingleThreadedExecutor` and `MultiThreadedExecutor` then you should make you're own executor, using one of those two as an example. They are fairly simple:

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/33a755c535d654c97401eb6d199580368c19eb40/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/executors/single_threaded_executor.hpp#L38-L63

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/33a755c535d654c97401eb6d199580368c19eb40/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/executors/single_threaded_executor.cpp#L21-L39

Then you can create an instance of your custom executor, add nodes to it, and then call spin on it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-11-14**:
Any help on the code? It is somewhat cryptic for me, I can not see where the thread is created...  I would like a fixed node:thread mapping which does not seem unusual to me, think nodes real-time and nodes non real-time. Any plans of adding such an executor?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-14**:\

> think nodes real-time and nodes not real-time.

[Mixed Real-Time Criticality with ROS2 - the Callback-group-level Executor](https://vimeo.com/292707644) ([slides](https://roscon.ros.org/2018/presentations/ROSCon2018_Lightning1_4.pdf)).

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-11-14**:
Just add each node to it's own `SingleThreadedExecutor`, and call `spin` on each of those executors in their own thread, and you can setup each thread to be a real-time priority thread or not.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-11-14**:
The only built-in executor that creates a thread is the `MultiThreadedExecutor`, see: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/33a755c535d654c97401eb6d199580368c19eb40/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.cpp#L48-L56

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-11-14**:
And if I would want this thread:node mapping and also reentrant callbacks? Could I `spin` each `MultiThreaderExecutor` in its own thread, and the threads created by that executor in its pool would inherit the parent thread's properties?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-11-14**:
I don't know, it depends on what priority your operating system gives to new threads. If they are not inherited, then you'd need to make a new `MultiThreadedExecutor` which modifies the priorities of the threads it creates before using them. But as I said the `MultiThreadedExecutor` is trivial.

**Comment by [uthinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/37306/uthinu/) on 2018-11-14**:
I do not know C++ well... Could you point me to an exact line in [MultiThreaderExecutor.cpp](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/master/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.cpp) where the threads are created?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-11-14**:\

> I do not know C++ well...

That won't mix well with writing real-time safe code...

I already linked to it, the `emplace_back`: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/33a755c535d654c97401eb6d199580368c19eb40/rclcpp/src/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.cpp#L48-L56